# BSON .native is not a function - Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, bson

I'm trying to run my Node Project in Ubuntu 16.04 from AWS. I'm using:

- Node v5.8.0
- Mongo 3.2.12
- Pm2 2.4.1

When I run the project using pm2 or node I get the following error:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-13-71:/var/www/ronteq$ node index.js 
/var/www/ronteq/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/ordered.js:15
var bson = new BSON.BSONPure();
           ^

TypeError: BSON.BSONPure is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/ronteq/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/ordered.js:15:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/ronteq/node_modules/mongodb/lib/apm.js:7:26)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
```

Is there something I've to change in my node_modules?

```
"use strict"

var inherits = require('util').inherits,
  f = require('util').format,
  EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter,
  BSON = require('bson').native().BSON, **Error Line**
  ReadPreference = require('./read_preference'),
```

In my local machine everything works fine. I've searched for a solution but nothing, someone has dealt with this error before?

Comment: Seeing this as well.  Did you find a solution?

Comment: Just wanted to check if you found solution for this one?